# Modelling two dependent hierarchies of classes

Tags: casting, structure, extend

I am facing a modelling probem that I try to simplify as much as possible in this post.

I consider a set of classes which extend a common class (called Letter here):

```
public abstract class Letter{
    public void commonMethod(){...}
}

public class A extends Letter{
    public void methodA(){...}
}

// Idem for several classes B, C, D, ...
```

I need to implement another set of classes. Each of them contains one Letter attribute and extends the same class (called UsesLetter here).

Here is how I am currently doing it (but I am wondering if there is a better way):

```
public abstract class UsesLetter{
    protected Letter l;

    public UsesLetter(Letter l){this.l = l;}
    public void commonMethod(){l.commonMethod();}
    public abstract void setLetterIfCompatible(Letter l);
}

public class UsesA extends UsesLetter{

    public UsesA(A a){super(l);}

    public void usesA(){((A)l).methodA();}

    @Override
    public boolean setLetterIfCompatible(Letter l){

        boolean result = false;
        if(l instanceof A){
            this.l = l;
        result = true;

        return result;

    }

    // Specific behavior of the class
    // ...

}

// Idem for several classes UsesA, UsesB, ...
// Note: several classes may use the same Letter class (e.g., UsesABis, UsesATer, ...)

// Example of use
public static void main(String[] args){

    UsesA ua = new UsesA(new A());
    UsesB ub = new UsesB(new B());

    // I want to be able to use the common and specific methods...
    ua.commonMethod();
    ua.usesA();
    ub.usesB();

    Letter l = new A();

    // ... and to change the letter
    if(ua.setLetterIfCompatible(l))
        ua.methodA();

}
```

I am not convinced this is the best way of implementing the behavior that I want as I need to cast the letters each time I want to use them.

Do you know if there is a better modelling? Maybe a design pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use generics:

```
public abstract class UsesLetter<LetterType extends Letter>{
    protected LetterType l;

    public UsesLetter(LetterType l){this.l = l;}
    public void commonMethod(){l.commonMethod();}
    public abstract void setLetter(LetterType l);
}

public class UsesA extends UsesLetter<A>{

    public UsesA(A a){super(a);}

    public void useA(){((A)l).methodA();}

    @Override
    public void setLetter(A a){
        l = a;
    }

    // Specific behavior of the class
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks! I did not think of generics. And the cast in "((A)l).methodA();" is not required anymore.